# Datalist Controls access in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i am using a `DataList` that contains a few `TextBox` within a table. i had tried the code is the code behind

```
TextBox txtbox = dlCRR.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
```

The error is

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

When i debug i am seeing a `null` value. why is this?

Comment: I'm confused by your code.  It look like you are mixing `C#` and `VB.NET`.

Comment: What IS null, exactly? `dlCRR`? `txtbox`?

Comment: Which event does throw this error? Please post more code.

Comment: asp.net C#     this is my code. TextBox txt = dlCRR.Items[1].FindControl("txtboxStudentImpact") as TextBox;

Comment: i have a table in a datalist where one column textbox ID is txtboxStudentImpact. There can be rows of data for this textbox. The idea is to retrieve the data from the series of textboxes for this txtboxStudentImpact textboxID.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to find the textbox directly from the datalist control. You will have to find it from the DataList.Items.

Ex:

```
TextBox txt = myDataList.Items[indexOfWhatIamLookingFor].FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
```

or if you want to iterate all items

```
foreach (DataListItem dli in myDataList.Items) 
{
    TextBox txt = dli.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
}
```

Comment: thanks much. how do i iterate through the TextBox txt? I want to know the content of each textbox so that i may then be able to edit them and then update the database.